# Глобальная библиотека на С

Tags: c

я изучаю язык программирования С, создал свою первую библиотеку и подключил её к своему проекту, но не могу найти как сделать чтобы ета библиотека была глобальной, то есть чтобы в другом проекте тоже мог её подключить, вот коды:
mylib.h:

```
#ifndef __mylib__
#define __mylib__
   void alert(char *str);
   void alert_ln(char *str);
#endif
```

mylib.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mylib.h"

void alert(char *str) {
  printf("%s", str);
  //выводит текст
}
void alert_ln(char *str) {
  //выводит текст с переходом на новую строку
  printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mylib.h"

int main(void) {
  alert("hello o");
  alert_ln("");
  alert_ln("hi");
}
```

Но проблема в том что данная библиотека доступна только в **етом** проекте, а в другом проекте она *не доступна,* как сделать так чтобы её можно было подключать в любом новом проекте?

Comment: Чтобы сделать библиотеку понадобится отдельный проект и dll интерфейс для ее, а у вас сейчас не библиотека, а просто единица трансляции текущего проекта. Также в каждом проекте надо будет указывать папки с заголовочными файлами и артефактами сборки библиотеки и линковать ее. Еще макросы начинающие с двух `_` зарезервированы.

Comment: Хорошо, а где я могу увидеть пример реализации?

Comment: Например https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170

Comment: И как подключить библиотеку через url? У меня код библиотеки тут: https://replit.com/@vova2020/biblprogramC#mylib.h

Comment: Никак. Такого не бывает. Библиотеки придется подсовывать локальные компилятору.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>           /// ищет в системном каталоге
#include "hot.h"             /// ищет в папке проекта
#include "/usr/biif/p.h"     /// ищет в каталоге /usr/biff
#include "a : stdio.h"       /// ищет на диске а
```

Все внешние файлы должны быть с блокировкой "только для чтения".
Ссылки должны быть максимально точными, а каталоги без русских букв.

Comment: А как свою библиотеку "зарегистрировать" в системном каталоге?

Comment: Вот такой файл <stdio.h> должен быть где-то рядом. Ищет во всех вложенных папках проекта, ищет в директории компилятора (все доступные папки и директории). Первое что найдёт - будет использовать по умолчанию.